# Papa Rudin $1.33$ theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, lebesgue-integral

**This is the definition which we need for the proof of the theorem**:
[image]

**There is the theorem:**

If $f$ $\in$ $L^1(\mu)$, then

$|\int_X f d\mu|$ $\leq$ $\int_X |f| d\mu $.

**There is the proof:**

Put $z$ $=$ $\int_x f d\mu$. Since $z$ is a complex number, there is a complex number $\alpha$, with $|\alpha|$ $=$ $1$, such that $\alpha$$z$ $=$ $|z|$. let $u$ be the real part of $\alpha$$f$. Then $u$ $\leq$ $|\alpha f|$ $=$ $|f|$. Hence

$|\int_X f d\mu|$ $=$ $\alpha$ $\int_X f d\mu$ $=$ $\int_X \alpha f d\mu $ $=$ $\int_X u d\mu $ $\leq$ $\int_X |f| d\mu $.

I don't understand how we conclude that there is a complex number $\alpha$, with $|\alpha|$ $=$ $1$, such that $\alpha z $ $=$ $|z|$, hence I also don't understand why should $|\alpha|$ be equal of $1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: HINT(S): How does comple multiplication work geometrically? If you have a complex number and you multiply it with another complex number whose modulus 1, where is the new number on the argand plane? Where is $|z|$ on the argand plane?

Comment: @PCeltide I don't know. please explain it explicitly . I really would be grateful

Comment: Hint: for $z\neq 0$, take $\alpha =|z|/z$. What is $|\alpha|$? What is $\alpha z$?

Comment: @Gary thank you man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**More Explicit Hint:** Let $z=re^{ix}$; then what should $\alpha$ be so that $\alpha z=|z|=r$?